# No rails in ubuntu whem i "cd" to project dir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I lose my patience to rails on ubuntu. So far I have used the ready environment on c9, but it is slowly closing. I'm learning how to deal with rails and I have a problem with Ubuntu.

I use tutorials (many) to install it. Finally, I did it, and I created a small project. One page + one model + one controller. Commit, exit, turn off a notebook.

Today when I want to back to programming I opened a terminal and go to project dir /Desktop/Projc/test. And after typed `rails s` I got the message:

```
Command 'rails' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install ruby-railties
```

And what is weird, If I open a terminal in home dir rails are ok. I can create a new project etc. But in the existing project rails "are not installed". 
I spent a few hours to look for a solution, reads many posts (so: 10918685, 7788946, 16884034) but nothing help.

I'm afraid that I just did a bigger mess. 
Can someone try to help me with my case?

My configs:
 `gem env`:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.1 (2019-01-30 patchlevel 33) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/iso/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/iso/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/iso/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/iso/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/iso/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/iso/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/iso/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1
     - /home/iso/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/iso/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin
     - /home/iso/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@global/bin
     - /home/iso/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin
     - /home/iso/.rvm/bin
     - /home/iso/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
     - /home/iso/.rbenv/shims
     - /home/iso/.rbenv/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /snap/bin
```

`echo $PATH`:

```
/home/iso/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin:/home/iso/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@global/bin:/home/iso/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin:/home/iso/.rvm/bin:/home/iso/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/iso/.rbenv/shims:/home/iso/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

`rails -v`: 5.2.3
`ruby -v`: 2.6.0p0

Can someone see a solution? And in the terminal, I have a checked a "run as start shell".

Comment: Just to be sure, can you completely close out of your terminal, reopen it, and try it? More often than not, it's an old bash profile without the updated bins...

Comment: I closed it (all windows, reboot) and opened terminal once again and whem I type 'rails s' I got a standard message to create new app etc. So rails works. I go to /project dir (same terminal window) type 'rails s' again and i got info than rails are not installed, command not found.

Comment: What happens if you type `./bin/rails`?

Comment: Hmm... i got a mssg than i using a old version of bundler: 
/home/iso/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:108:in `warn_for_outdated_bundler_version': You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile. (Bundler::LockfileError)

Comment: Ok i update bundler, install bundles and i got now: The most common rails commands are:....... (looks normal) but 'rails s' and other commands in this dir are still not found :/

Comment: Try to perform `rails new my_app` inside your home dir, `cd my_app`, `bundle install`, and then `rails s`. Let me know if it's the same error.

Comment: I did what u say. Create one app in home, one app in desktop. Everything works until reboot. Now when i go to a home app i can normally run rails s. But when i go to desktop app i have same info as in first example : rails are not found

Comment: Sounds like that app has an issue, not your rails install. So, delete the app and reclone it from GitHub.

Comment: But when I creating a home app as u said I created a new desktop app too, just for test. First work, second nope. So it looks like the problem is with desktop dir? :O

Comment: I suppose so but it's too complex for me to figure that out without knowing a hell of a lot more. Sounds like you might need to uninstall and reinstall everything but it could be as simple as RVM only running in home, etc.

Comment: What is output of `rvm list` from home folder and als from root of the problem rails project?

Comment: Why do you have RVM and rbenv simultaneously? I recommend to delete both first and then install only one.